# Low Search prefetch number of entries

Tags: low-search, low

I'm trying to pre-fetch the number of results available per year for a specific category of articles.

The [loopee](https://github.com/danott/ee-loopee) module allows me to loop from current year back to 1999.
I would like to show a filter available (possibly with the number of entries available) only if there are results for that specific year and that specific category.

Example:

**Sports**

[2016(**5**)](http://#) | [2015(**4**)](http://#) …

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="articles" style="linear"}
    <h1>{category_name}</h1>
    {exp:loopee forint="{current_time format="%Y"}" to="1999" by="-1" parse="inward}
        {exp:low_search:filters query="{segment_3}"}
(IF) ONLY SHOW FOLLOWING CODE IF THERE ARE ENTRIES AVAILABLE                
            <span>
                <a href="{low_search:url collection="articles" category="{category_id}" search:anno="{loopee_value}"}">{loopee_value}(X) | </a>
            </span>
(/END IF)
       {/exp:low_search:filters}
    {/exp:loopee}   
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not something Low Search can do for you. You generate the form (or links) that contain the parameters to filters. LS uses a combination of native and its own filters, and EE lacks the API to get to *just* a results count based on those params (ie. Generating context-aware totals per parameter value)